# Real world examples of "Git as application database"

Tags: git

I found an intriguing sentence in Pro Git by Scott Chacon:

> Git as a content-addressable filesystem is a very powerful tool that you can easily use as more than just a VCS.

And [js-git](https://github.com/creationix/js-git):

> It also enables using git as a database to replace SQL and no-SQL data stores in many applications.

But I could not find any real world examples of "Git as application database."

Are there any?

Comment: I'm not sure about "real world". There are attempts to use the engine as a base for several things though. [Here](https://github.com/artagnon/phoenixfs) is one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if your application's data can be managed in files you can implement the data access layer or a part of it with git. Instead of just using files you benefit from version control.

I even think that it is possible to emulate transaction concepts with the index (staging area).

Git might also be a reasonable data access implementation choice if you think about applications that operate offline and sync their data when they are online again. That's exactly what git is made for.

I guess the idea of using git in an data access layer of an application is relative new and therefore there are less applications that use it already. Java developers might want to use the [jgit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) api.

Java developers who want to manage their application's data in a hierarchical structure might want to use [modeshape](http://modeshape.jboss.org/) and the [git connector](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Git+connector).

Maybe modeshape is a real world example of using git for data acceess to you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my first answer...

The answer comes from the inventor of git Linus Torvalds. In 2014 he made a post on [google+](https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/X2XVf9Q7MfV) about using git as an application's data management.

> So me and +Dirk Hohndel (who maintains subsurface, I long since gave up that role) have been idly talking about better save formats for months now. But binary formats are evil and generally not extensible, and besides, you want replication and network transparency, plus the ability to combine dives from many different sources. Binary blobs are just horrible for all of these things.
>
> So I've wanted to use the +Git object database format, because it's actually very well designed if I say so myself. Not only does efficient deduplication and compression, it has the advantage that it still does a really good job at line-based textual representations, while allowing a very natural representation of multiple different events as separate files, with git itself tying it all together.

Git is used in the application [subsurface](http://subsurface-divelog.org/) (developed by Linus Torvalds and others). Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface) at github and you will see it (git-access.c, load-git.c, save-git.c, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[Gerrit Code Review](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) started out with a relational database for storing everything except the Git data itself, but work has been ongoing for quite some time to shift everything to configuration files in the gits themselves. I can't find a good document that describes how everything works and what the roadmap is, but you can probably dig up good bits and pieces from the [mailing list archives](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/repo-discuss).